# Simplify Boolean Indexing Conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have two columns which either contain a "Yes" or "No" value:

- Partner
- Dependents

I originally wrote this code to generate another column based off the value in those two columns (see below):

```
conditions = [
    # either dependents, partner, or both 
    ((cleaned_df["Partner"] == "Yes") & (cleaned_df["Dependents"] == "Yes")) | ((cleaned_df["Partner"] == "No") & (cleaned_df["Dependents"] == "Yes")) | ((cleaned_df["Partner"] == "Yes") & (cleaned_df["Dependents"] == "No")),
    # neither partner nor dependents
    (cleaned_df["Partner"] == "No") & (cleaned_df["Dependents"] == "No")
]
```

However, the first condition is a bit wordy and I was wondering if there was a more eloquent way to rewrite this code. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will take a minimum example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Partner' : ['Yes','No','Yes','No'] , 'Dependents': ['No','No','Yes','Yes']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
Partner Dependents
0   Yes No
1   No  No
2   Yes Yes
3   No  Yes
```

You can simply do:

```
(df["Partner"] == "Yes") | (df["Dependents"] == "Yes")

0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Explanation: If any one is True then it will be `True`, if both of them are `False` then it will be `False.`

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
dict1 = {'colA': {0: 'a0', 1: 'a1', 2: 'a2', 3: 'a3', 4: 'a4'}, 
         'Partner': {0: 'Yes', 1: 'Yes', 2: 'No', 3: 'No', 4: 'Yes'}, 
         'Dependents': {0: 'Yes', 1: 'No', 2: 'Yes', 3: 'No', 4: 'No'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

`df`

```
    colA    Partner Dependents
0   a0      Yes     Yes
1   a1      Yes     No
2   a2      No      Yes
3   a3      No      No
4   a4      Yes     No
```

---

**Code**

indexing two columns and make to boolean and use `any` func

```
df[['Partner', 'Dependents']].eq('Yes').any(axis=1)
```

result:

```
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

make result to condition column

```
df.assign(conditions=df[['Partner', 'Dependents']].eq('Yes').any(axis=1))
```

`df`

```
    colA    Partner Dependents  conditions
0   a0      Yes     Yes         True
1   a1      Yes     No          True
2   a2      No      Yes         True
3   a3      No      No          False
4   a4      Yes     No          True
```

Answer (score 0):

Like other answers, you are looking for the OR table (`|`):

```
>>> df_or
  Partner Dependents  Expected
0      No         No     False
1      No        Yes      True
2     Yes         No      True
3     Yes        Yes      True
```

However an interesting table as suggested by @Phoenix is the NOR table (`^`):

```
>>> df_nor
  Partner Dependents  Expected
0      No         No      True
1      No        Yes     False
2     Yes         No     False
3     Yes        Yes     False
```

So just check if Partner and Dependents is "No" and invert the mask:

```
>>> ~(df['Partner'].eq('No') & df['Dependents'].eq('No'))
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool
```

More concise way:

```
>>> ~df[['Partner', 'Dependents']].eq('No').all(axis=1)
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool
```

So your final should be something like:

```
m = df[['Partner', 'Dependents']].eq('Yes').any(axis=1)
conditions = [m, ~m]
```

With numpy, you can use:

```
# val1 for "either dependents, partner, or both" condition
# val2 for "neither partner nor dependents"
df['Target'] = np.where(m, "val1", "val2")
```